# Invite facebook friends without using "presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession"

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing an app which perform following things.

1. Listing facebook friends.
2. User should select friends from list.
3. User should invite selected friends.

Above two steps are working fine.
I am also able to invite friends using **[FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:]**

But this method open Facebook SDK's inbuilt dialog box, into which i select friends.

Is there any way by which I can directly invite friends without calling **[FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:]** method.

Comment: no there is no way by which you can invite facebook friends without using FBWebDialogs

Comment: But I see this functionality in some app like "Diamond Dash".

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/